# print item in a list free marker

Tags: xml, freemarker

i have an XML list. i need to print the price according to the date.
this is what im trying to do:
how can i gat,say, the price of the key="2017-03-31">99.85301833??

```
<#list reportData.allProductPrices as x>${x},</#list>
```

or

```
${reportData.allProductPrices?first}
```

this is my XML:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use XPath for the last step:

```
${reportData.allProductPrices['item[@key="2017-03-31"]']}
```

Comment: it didn't help. apparently there are more factors to take into consideration. but thank you for your help.